# Can't able to select values from the Drop-down box using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium

[image]I am trying to take the locator of drop-down box but it's giving error

> "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element
>   should have been "select" but was "input"".

My Xpath is:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//simple-dropdown-field[@label='Authorization System Type']//input[@id='state']")
static WebElement systemTypedropDown;
```

Here is the code from which i am trying to take the locator.

[image]

Comment: This code didn't throw the exception, but the message is very clear, `Select` class need element with `<select>` tag. You need to click on the dropdown to open it and then click the option.

Comment: @Guy .. this is my solution, same i tried:  public boolean select_AuthSyetemType() throws Exception
    {
        systemTypedropDown.click();
        //Thread.sleep(2000);
        Select select = new Select(systemTypedropDown);
        select.selectByVisibleText("AZURE");
        return true;

    }

Comment: Again, 'Select' class can use only select tag. You can't use it with input tag.

Comment: Then What should I do?? need to create another method??

Comment: When Drop Down gets open and when i am trying to take webelement of the same then it get disabled. just after clicking to select cursor, this goes off, unable to take xpath of the elements

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Why are you not try to find element `By.id('state')`?.. if element's id is unique.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur there are n no of elements present in id:state, I am able to click that drop down but unable to select from the list

Comment: Then you should try to select element from list in 2 step, because it is not simple select box, you should first clicck on that drop down and and then try to find list item by text with `WebDriverWait`, so that you can find it.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur that is not working, pls suggest me any other options,

Comment: If you want to click on `AZURE` element, you can use `.//li[text()='AZURE']` xpath to click on item.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I have one more doubt, in that html code there are some more drop-down but that drop-down html code does not have a list so how can i get the locator for this kind of code.
Please give me a suggestion for solving this issue.

<div class="ra-dropdown-wrapper"><div class="ra-dropdown-selected pull-left"><div ng-focus="showSectionsDropdown = true" ng-blur="showSectionsDropdown = false" tabindex="0" class="side-padding-10"><span>Controller</span> <img src="src/images/sort_icon.png" class="pull-right"></div><!----></div></div></div>

Comment: And when that type of dropdown contains list?

Comment: There is no list for other drop down element

Comment: If there is no list, what do you want to select then?

Comment: Kindly check my screenshot as the dropdown does not have data in the list. @SaurabhGaur

Comment: @SaurabhGaur pls reply